# Python - How to update datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime

When I call on datetime.now() in my program it calls the current time, but when I call it again, it displays the previous time. How can I update datetime.now() so it calls the current time eachtime?

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Call it again. Each time you do `var = datetime.now()`, var has the value of the current time. The value doesn't update.

Comment: As @Primusa implied, what you're saying is probably different than what you're actually doing. Please provide some actual code.

Comment: So when I directly call datetime.now() I do not have the issue. However, when I assign a variable to it and then call the variable, thats when I get the issue.

Comment: You only can call a *callable* - a return value of `datetime.now()` is not callable.

Comment: You have to get `start = datetime.now()` ...then do something and later  `end = datetime.now()` -  to have the elapsed time get `elapsed = end - start` if needed.

Comment: @AjayShah you still have not posted your actual code. The additional description in the comments is equally confusing to the original post.

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> but when I call it again

... but you're **NOT** calling it again. You're more-than-likely printing/outputting the value of the variable that the *first* datetime.now() was assigned to.

Let's say you have the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

first_time = str(datetime.now())
print('First datetime.now() value: %s' % first_time)
```

You're probably attempting to get the updated time by simply printing `first_time` (what you *incorrectly* refer to as *"calling"*).

Instead, you should either overwrite `first_time` by reassigning *datetime.now()* to it, or you should declare a new variable and assign *datetime.now()* to it.

```
# Overwriting & outputting:
# first_time = datetime.now()

# Declaring a new (updated) value (what I'll use in the example):
second_time = datetime.now()

# Outputting:
print('first_time: %s\nsecond_time: %s' % (str(first_time), str(second_time)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define as follows:

```
def now():
          return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

use the definition in the following way:

```
print('{}'.format(now()))
```